# Dynamics 365 SharePoint Online Folder creation based on entity. How to create folder for already existing CRM records

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I have enabled SharePoint online integration with Dynamics.

It creates folder as and when I navigate to Documents Tab.

My question is how to create these folders for already existing Records. I do not want to navigate to each of the records and then click on Documents tab and then let CRM/SharePoint create folder.

Is there any trigger which I could do programmatically so that folder will be created automatically.

Note: I can create SharePoint Document location record per hand orprogrammatically but then I would be needed to give Folder name as (`<Record Primary Name><Record Guid>`) which I would like to avoid.

Reason: SharePoint and CRM does neglect special characters which are not allowed in SharePoint and I do not want this headache of looking for correct name. I want CRM/SharePoint to perform just it should happen for already existing records.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

I was using on-demand workflow in similar situation. You can try with creating of on-demand workflow with step which would create document location. Here you have [nice guidelines](https://crmbook.powerobjects.com/system-administration-in-dynamics-365/sharepoint-document-management/beyond-basic-integration/bulk-creating-sharepoint-folders-and-automatic-integration-with-dynamics-crm/).

[image: create SP folder]
Image [source](https://crmbook.powerobjects.com/system-administration-in-dynamics-365/sharepoint-document-management/beyond-basic-integration/bulk-creating-sharepoint-folders-and-automatic-integration-with-dynamics-crm/)

Comment: Well I end up doing the same but with power automate. However there is one flaw in this solution. If your record primary name has special characters which are not allowed by sharepoint, it will fail. This is the exact fail case I wished to overcome with out of box folder creation on sharepoint.